# Apache Tika ArchiveStreamFactory.detect error

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, apache-tika

I'm using java with apache tika 1.18 to convert some files to TXT.
When I try to use the AutoDetectParser(), I'm getting the error :

[ERROR   ] Error occurred during error handling, give up!
org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveStreamFactory.detect(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljava/lang/String;
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault:162'
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveStreamFactory.detect(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveStreamFactory.detect(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljava/lang/String;

I was dinging on internet and found this error related wrong version of commom_compress, appears this method doesn't exist in versions previous of 1.14 of commom_compress. In my case the version is 1.16.1.

After build the project, I checked the libs inside and there is only the correct version.

I'm using IBM Liberty 18.0 ... and now I'm really lost about options to solve this problem.

When I use the specific parser, like PDFParser(), everything works fine!

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What build tool and dependency manager are you using? What else is on your classpath that might be adding the old commons compress jar by mistake?

Comment: I'm using maven

Comment: Check your full dependency tree then, including transitive ones, to spot where the old commons compress dependency is coming in, then exclude that old one!

Answer (score 0):

## Source of the issue:

`Spark 2.x` distributions include old versions of commons-compress, while `Tika` library depends on version 1.18 of `commons-compress` library.

## Solution

Use --driver-class-path argument in your spark-shell or spark-submit to point to a the right version of commons-compress library.

```
spark-submit 
     --driver-class-path ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.18/commons-compress-1.18.jar
     --class {you.main.class}
....
```

[Check my detailed answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505752/spark-2-x-tika-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-commons-compress-archi/55772226#55772226)